# SQL command to delete "pending comments" doesn't work...?

Tags: comments, sql

This is the SQL command:

```
DELETE FROM wp_comments WHERE comment_approved = 0
```

This, as you can see in the screenshot below, says that the operation was executed ok but no rows affected....which is odd b/c I have 13,000 pending comments that I am trying to delete!

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

There is a plugin that does this but it crashes when I use it - most likely b/c I have 13K comments that need deleting from the pending state...

Thanks for all help

[image]

Comment: If you change `DELETE` to `SELECT *` do you see any of the comments? Are you sure `comment_approved` is the right value to check? Are you definitely looking at the correct database?

Comment: yes you are right - how odd....the reply was "No rows"

Comment: But, where else could the "pending comments" go?

Comment: Pending comments should be `comment_approved = 0`, so if you're not seeing any then I'd guess either you're not actually looking for "Pending" comments. They must have another status. _Or_ you're not looking in the right database. Is anything returned for `SELECT * FROM wp_comments`? Without any condition?

Comment: It only pulls up one comment - weird thing is that I have 13,000 pending comments that I am trying to delete... - not sure what other database I can look in...

Comment: Ok yeah, you're definitely looking in the wrong database. Check wp-config.php to see what database you're connected to or ask your host.

Comment: define( 'DB_NAME', 'local' ); is the name of the Database - also, I should add that I am working on a local machine (using Flywheel that ships with a built in mySQL) - there can only be "one comments" DB right?

Comment: I have no idea. That’s a question for Flywheel. Are you deleting comments from your local site or from the live site?

Comment: From the dev site - basically I cloned it locally so that I can do things like this...

Comment: Well you don't appear to have cloned the comments.